# Cleaner links with routing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I want to do a dummy Netflix clone in Codeigniter, but i have problem with routes, for example, my route looks like this:

> http://localhost/NotFlix/index.php/add_page

I would like it to be nicer like:

> http://localhost/NotFlix/add_page

This is my link to site in header:

```
<a href="./index.php/add_page">Dodaj film</a>
```

And this is my route file:

```
$route['index.php/add_page'] = 'add_page';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change .htaccess file located root folder(not in the application folder).
If there is no that file then pls create the file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

After then
your router

```
$route['add_page'] = 'add_page';
```

your config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php/';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Then you can use a tag like the following.

```
<a href = "<?=base_url()?>add_pagex">Dodaj film</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me